# jQuery promise inside promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am creating array from ajax promise and after that I want to run my code. For that first loop each inside that loop ajax promise fetch record and add to the array and On first each loop promise I am running my code but each is promise is complete before array completed

`my code`

```
var attendeesId = []
 $('.tags-container > div[data-email]')
          .each(function() {
getCustomRequest(url).then(function(data) { //ajax promise function
              attendeesId.push(data.d.Id)
            })
})
.promise()
.done(function() {
console.log(attendeesId) //this runs before and shows empty
})
```

What I am doing wrong over here

Comment: The `getCustomRequest` is not connected to anything outside. I'd ditch the jQuery and use `Promise.all` instead

Comment: Kindly can you give me example @CertainPerformance

Comment: Something like `Promise.all([...$('.tags-container > div[data-email]')].map(() => getCustomRequest(url).then(data => data.d.Id)))`